# Is there a way to hide the Persons tab in Sharepoint 365?

Tags: user-profile, user

I don´t want my users to see each other but they do if Persons tab is enabled. Can it be disabled?

Comment: Are you saying that you want to disable people search? In it's current state your question is quite difficult to comprehend.

Comment: ... or do you want to disable user profiles altogether? Please add more details to the question.

Comment: What I want is to disable people search so that users can't see each others emails. Basically it is to prevent users spamming each other.

Answer (score 1):

In both SharePoint 2010 and 2013 the "Tab" that you refer too is just a pointer to a page. You can delete the page, but that does not prevent someone who knows what they are doing from using search to find user profiles.

If that is what you want you need to omit the user profile crawl in the search service application. Find the content source start address that begins with sps3:// and remove the entry.